# Why is it so common to find answers with more upvotes than questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer, answers, up-votes

I was reading through some interesting questions this weekend and realized that there are a number of questions with less up votes than the answer.
I'm intrigued about this "phenomenon". If a question triggers a very well received answer I would expect the same appreciation to the question.

Does anyone have a different point of view? Am I trying to relate things that are not related?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with you, that if a question is worth answering then it is also worth up voting.

When questions have 2 or 3 answers each with up-votes but the question itself is sat on 0 votes, I think it could become disheartening for those who have asked the question to engage further with our site and community.

Comment: That's true. The first year I upvoted most questions, but in time I (we) tend to upvote less because we have seen so much similar questions...  but still they deserve the upvote. Let's not get lazy ;-)

Comment: See also: [If a question is worth answering, why isn't it worth upvoting](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/a/461/17222). Sometimes the question is easier to compose than the research and explanation necessary to provide a complete answer to both the exact question and similar ones that might be marked as a duplicate in the future.

Answer (score 2):

For questions, the up-vote button is titled "*This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear*".

Consider (made up examples):

- "*I read that …*" [*Where* did you read it?]
- "*I read that …*" [But exactly what did it say?]
- "*T͟h͟i͟s͟  says that …*" [The link is to a textbook; are *we* expected to read it all?]
- "*T͟h͟i͟s͟ web page says that …*" [It took me 10 minutes to find some text that *might* have been misread as meaning that.]
- …

Other questions:

- Have the question in the Body that's significantly different from the one in the Title.
- Have very poor spelling and grammar, and blatant typos.
- Have little or no punctuation.
- Have one monolithic paragraph.
- Ramble on without getting to the point and then expect the reader to figure out exactly what is being asked.
- …

In many cases, a posting can contain a fundamentally good question that generates some excellent answers, while itself showing no research and being poorly worded.

Those answers deserve up-votes.
The question doesn't.